# How to extract reviews from facebook public page without page access token?

Tags: r, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract reviews from public facebook pages like airline page, hospital page, to perform sentiment analysis. I have app id and app secret id which i generated from facebook graph API using my facebook account, But to extract the reviews I need page access token and as I am not the owner/admin of the page so I can not generate that page access token. Is any one know how to do it or it requires some paid service?

Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without a Page Token of the Page, it is impossible to get the reviews/ratings. You can only get those for Pages you own. There is no paid service either, you can only ask the Page owners to give you access.